# Can I make a method in an abstract class which constructs an instance for the instantiating class?

Tags: java, constructor, abstract-class

I have two classes that extend an an abstract Model. Both classes implement a method called instance() to basically ensure that there is only one instance of the class at any time. The structure of instance() is exactly the same for both classes, so I thought it would be nice to move it up a level to the abstract class. However, the method calls the instantiating class' default constructor. Is it possible to call this constructor from the abstract class? If so how? What other approaches might work for generalizing this method?

### Simplified Example Classes

I have an abstract class for a Model which looks like

```
public abstract class Models{
    public List<Model> models = new ArrayList<Model>();

    /** load the different models, with the models with pre-trained model*/
    public abstract void load();
}
```

And two instanciating classes which like this

```
 public class PageLanguageModels extends Models {
     /** ensure we only call one of them */
     protected static PageLanguageModels _instance = null;
     static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductLanguageModels.class.getName());

     public static synchronized PageLanguageModels instance() {
         if (_instance == null) {
             try {
                 _instance = new PageLanguageModels();
                 _instance.load();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't load language models.", e);
             }
         }

         return _instance;
     }

     /** load the different models, with the models with pre-trained model*/
     @Override
     public void load() {
         models.clear();
         models.add(new BOWModel());
     }
 }

 public class ProductLanguageModels extends Models {
     /** ensure we only call one of them */
     protected static ProductLanguageModels _instance = null;
     static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ProductLanguageModels.class.getName());

     public static synchronized ProductLanguageModels instance() {
         if (_instance == null) {
             try {
                 _instance = new ProductLanguageModels();
                 _instance.load();
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't load language models.", e);
             }
         }

         return _instance;
     }

     /** load the different models, with the models with pre-trained model*/
     @Override
     public void load() {
         models.clear();
         models.add(new Word2VecModel());
     }
 }
```

### Attempted Approaches

I have tried using a factory method pattern, but this doesn't work because instance is a static method and the abstract factory method cannot be called from a static method.

> Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method makeModels()
>   from the type Models

```
public abstract class Models{

    /** load the different models, with the models with pre-trained model*/
    public abstract void load();

    //Factory method
    public abstract Models makeModels();

    // Instance code moved up from instanciating classes        
    protected static Models _instance = null;
    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Models.class.getName());

    public static synchronized Models instance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            try {
                _instance = makeModels();
                _instance.load();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Couldn't load language models.", e);
            }
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't create a static method in an abstract class. Using a Factory or a Builder class in your case may help. As a side note, to create singletons without synchronization, you can use the Holder pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can move all of your instantiating logic to a parent class due to its static nature and issues regarding type erasure, but you surely can organize your code in order to make it reusable. I wrote a simple copy/paste example for you by changing your design just a little bit with focus on the instantiation part, so I left out some attributes and logging code:

**An interface**

```
public interface Models {
    void load();
}
```

**An abstract implementation**

```
public abstract class BaseModels implements Models {

    protected static <T extends Models> T instance(Class<T> type, T candidate) {
        if (candidate == null) {
            try {
                candidate = type.newInstance();
                candidate.load();
            } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return candidate;
    }
}
```

**A concrete implementation**

```
public class HeroModels extends BaseModels {

    static HeroModels instance;

    public static HeroModels instance() {
        instance = instance(HeroModels.class, instance);
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        System.out.println("Loading HeroModels...");
    }
}
```

**A simple test case**

```
public class TestDrive {

    @Test
    public void testEquality() {

        HeroModels a1 = HeroModels.instance();
        HeroModels a2 = HeroModels.instance();

        Assert.assertEquals(a1, a2);

        System.out.println("a1: " + a1);
        System.out.println("a2: " + a2);
    }
}
```

**Test case output**

`Loading HeroModels... 
a1: HeroModels@736e9adb 
a2: HeroModels@736e9adb`

From the output you can see that the `HeroModels` class was loaded only once. The `instance(...)` method in `BaseModel` class is made protected to make clear it is intended to be used by children, which may have their own static instance attribute.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but you might want to extract it to a separate class.

Comment: Can you add a bit more explanation? For your original answer, I was able to google "Factory Pattern". But here I don't have much to go on for how to explore your suggestion.